# Django to pass through some urls to base apache

Tags: django, apache

Is there a way for Django to pass through some urls to whatever apache would resolve them too?

For instance, if I type in: http://< my-ip >. Is there a way to have django just serve up whatever is in /var/www/html/index.html?

Similarly, if I type in http://< my-ip >/devel, is there a way to make django simply serve what's in /var/www/html/devel/?

Basically, I want some urls to "not be touched".

Thanks!

**Edit** 
Following Anentropic's comment, I'd like Apache to call Django *only* if it can't match the url. How would I need to change httpd.conf to do that? Let's say I want Django to respond to *only* /polls/, /admin/ and /accounts/.

Here's the relevant portion from my httpd conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName <My IP ADDRESS>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py



# Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
# <Location /phpmyadmin>
#     SetHandler None
# </Location>
<Directory /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/media>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

LogLevel warn

Alias /media/ /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/media/

Alias /static/ /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/static/

<Directory /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need to do this the other way around, have Apache first try and match a URL in `/var/www/html` and if it doesn't match, only then pass the URL to django.

Comment: What Burhan said: do it the other way around. Serving things through Django is a bad idea: web servers are optimized for that kind of thing, not django.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid is correct - it is Apache which first gets the url, in a typical wsgi set up it is passing all urls through to Django... you want Apache to do something different with certain urls and pass the rest through to your Django app

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita's comment is confusing because obviously you will be 'serving things through Django' - Django is your webapp, the only way to use Django is by having it serve things. He means "don't serve static files with Django" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production

Comment: @Anentropic: Point made, but how do I get it to first try to match a url in /var/www/html and then to Django? I put up my httpd.conf file if that helps?

Comment: all I can suggest is read the Apache docs, it's all possible from the Apache side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to serve static html pages you could use [the flatpages app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/).
Again if you'd like to use different languages (php etc) I believe that you'd have to set up different virtual host in you apache config file to catch the url before it gets served to Django and redirect it to the correct folder. i.e:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  staging.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/staging/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  dev.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/dev/
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName <My IP ADDRESS>

Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
<Location /phpmyadmin>
     SetHandler None
</Location>
<Directory /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

LogLevel warn

WSGIScriptAlias /polls /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptAlias /admin /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptAlias /accounts /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/apache/wsgi.py

Alias /media/ /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/media/

Alias /static/ /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/static/

<Directory /home/ec2-user/srv/mysite/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'd like to do the opposite, catch the urls that are directed towards Django and redirect them appropriately. How would I redirect the urls /polls/, /admin/ and /accounts/ to Django only using the httpd.conf above? Thank you!

Comment: I'm still at work so I can't test it right now but you could try defining everything else before defining your WSGIScriptAlias for Django and then mapping it to a specific URI, for example:

`WSGIScriptAlias /polls /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py` instead of
`WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py`

That should preform a lookup on all other urls and then redirect it to your django application.

Comment: I've tried that before. However, then Django sees a path of "" when i got to my-server-ip/polls. It doesn't see "polls".

Comment: The only thing that I can think of right now is to set up your Django app under another Alias so you could access everything through /foo (i.e: foo/polls or foo/admin).

If not you could set up your Aliases above your WSGIScript however if an unknown Alias is requested, it will fall back onto Django.